# Xamarin Forms Cross Platform App Authentication with Firebase

Tags: firebase, authentication, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I want to take the users email and send them a reset password request.
I haven't had any luck with the solution.

```
private async void ForgetPassword_Clicked(object sende, EventArgs e)
        {

            var authReset = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(WebAPIkey));
            try
            {
                var email = UserLoginEmail.Text;

                var auth = await authReset.SendPasswordResetEmailAsync(UserLoginEmail.Text);
                var content = await auth.GetFreshAuthAsync();
                var serializedcontent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
                Preferences.Set("MyFirebaseRefreshToken", serializedcontent);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Invalid email or password", "OK");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. But if there is a better way, please let me know

```
private async void ForgetPassword_Clicked(object sende, EventArgs e)
    {

        var authReset = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(WebAPIkey));
        try
        {
            var email = UserLoginEmail.Text;

            var auth = authReset.SendPasswordResetEmailAsync(UserLoginEmail.Text);
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Email Sent", "OK");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Invalid email or password", "OK");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please accept it as answer. It will help others who have similar issue.